# Extract html conform language value from pythons locale package

Tags: python, html, lang

I create HTML output with a Python script.
The `<head>` tag need a `lang=` attribute.

I wan't to use Python's `locale` package for this. But the values from `locale` (e.g. `de_DE`) are not HTML conform. e.g. `de_DE` is not accepted by the W3C validator but `de` is.

So I do it that way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import locale

locale_lang = locale.getlocale()[0]  # e.g. 'de_DE'

html_lang_value = locale_lang.split('_')[0]  # e.g. 'de'

head_tag = f'<head lang="{html_lang_value}">'

print(head_tag)  # <head lang="de">
```

The question is if this is a good idea and will work in all languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`locale.get_locale` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getlocale) it

> Returns the current setting for the given locale category as sequence
> containing *language code*, *encoding*.(...)Except for the code `'C'`,
> the language code corresponds to [RFC 1766](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1766.html). *language code* and
> *encoding* may be `None` if their values cannot be determined.

Note that if *language code* will be `'C'` then your `locale_lang.split('_')[0]` will be `'C'`. Are you allowed to accept such value as `lang` attribute value? More importantly *langauge code* might be `None` which will crash your code as you must not `.split` `None`, so if your code must work reliably then you should be prepared for getting `locale_lang` value as `None`.